# Otimizar foreach

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, foreach

Preciso verificar se os itens da `listaContrato` existem na `listaPendencia`, se não existir eu seto o `enable` pra false para ser desabilitado na tela.

O que posso fazer para melhorar a performance do `foreach` abaixo? Ambas as listas são `List<>`.

Caso haja soluções que não sejam `foreach` também são bem-vindas.

```
foreach (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox item in pendenciaController.ListaCliente)
{
    item.IsEnabled = false;

    foreach (Pendencia pendencia in pendenciaController.ListaPendencia)
    {
        if (pendencia.ClienteNome.Equals(item.Content))
        {
            item.IsEnabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Denis, seja bem-vindo ao SOpt. Você está na comunidade de língua portuguesa, por gentileza traduza a sua questão. Recomendo que faça um [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pela comunidade.

Comment: Grande @Denis aqui é o Stackoverflow Brasil, idioma Português do Brasil, por favor faça as devidas traduções...

Comment: Feito! Agora por gentileza retire o voto negativo =)

Comment: Não é obrigação dizer, mas, o voto não foi meu @Denis só para deixar bem claro.

Comment: Eu sei que não foi...

Comment: Você poderia melhorar o contexto, é obrigado fazer esses dois foreach?

Comment: Editei Virgilio.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade acredito que vc tenha negativado, ainda mereço o negativo?

Comment: @Denis já removi, você não tem mais negativos na questão :D

Comment: Agradecido! hehe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu não tenho como testar, mas tente o seguinte LINQ (mas duvido que seja mais rápido que um for).

```
var lista = 
    from checkBox in pendenciaController.ListaCliente
    join pendencia in pendenciaController.ListaPendencia on checkBox.Content equals pendencia.ClienteNome into pendencias
    from pendencia in pendencias.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { CheckBox = checkBox, Pendencia = pendencia };

foreach (var item in lista)
{
    item.CheckBox.IsEnabled = item.Pendencia != null;
}
```

Comment: sua bruxaria rs fez cair muito o tempo! Uma de 9 segundos caiu pra menos de 1!!! You WIN!!!

Answer (score 4):

Aparentemente só para melhorar quebrando o laço assim que encontrar o que espera. Sem ver um contexto maior não dá para melhorar mais.

Dá para escrever isso do jeito mais idiomático para C#, pode evitar essa *flag*:

```
foreach (var item in pendenciaController.ListaContrato) {
    foreach (var pendencia in pendenciaController.ListaPendencia) {
        if (pendencia.Contrato.Equals(item.Content)) {
            item.IsEnabled = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/IterateItems.cs).

Comment: com o break melhorou 40% um dos foreach caiu de 9 pra 5 segundos.

Comment: Caso não encontre outra solução irei marcar a sua como resposta.